# Can't understand a code snippet using Pandas library in Python 3 involving slicing tabular data in chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm reading a guide where we slice the tabular data into chunksizes of 15 and then process it. But i'm having trouble understanding the code. I don't have access to a teacher hence I have asked here additionally the internet doesn't have a specific solution for my problem.
Thank You

[image]

This is code could someone please explain how exactly it's able to take each value in a loop and calculate the mean?

```
data_chunks = pd.read_csv("../data/microbiome.csv", chunksize=14)

mean_tissue = pd.Series({chunk.iloc[0].Taxon:chunk.Tissue.mean() for chunk in data_chunks})
```

Comment: I can't tell what the code is attempting to do, but `for chunk in data_chunks` will iterate over column names, so it is strage that it then calls `.Taxon` and `.Tissue`... what is the output of that line? What is the expected result? Can you please edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the different types of "Taxon" are 14 records long, so that is why they iterate through the [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) in 14 long chunks. (See first line! `chunksize=14`) Chunk is a part of the DataFrame, similar to slicing and indexing: here a chunk will have 14 rows and as many columns as the original DataFrame. The first chunk will contain the first 14 rows, the second will contain the second 14 rows and so on.

Next it creates a pandas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), you can think of this like a fancy 1d array, or list, or 1d version of the DataFrame. (See `pd.Series(...)`)

What will be in this Series instance? A *dictionary* (see the curly brackets!). The keys in this dictionary will be the `Taxon` type the chunk contains, and the value will be the mean of `Tissue` values in the current chunk (14 rows):

- `chunk.iloc[0].Taxon` selects the first row of the chunk, then it's value in the column `Taxon`
- `chunk.Tissue.mean()` will select every Tissue value in the chunk (14 values) then take the average of it
- `chunk.iloc[0].Taxon : chunk.Tissue.mean()` will pair up the aforementioned values in `key : value` fashion

They do this for every chunk: adding a new key and value pair to the dictionary each time (like list comprehension, only this is [dict comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension)). The pandas Series has a constructor that accepts a dictionary.

If you have any remaining questions feel free to ask and I will try to answer it.

Comment: Yes I understood perfectly. Thanks!